# try, catch, finally autocomplete pattern in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

Using `IntelliJ` when i type try followed by `Ctrl-Space` (autocomplete), i get nothing added

Instead, i'd like to see

```
  try {
    // do something great
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => // handle me
  }
```

Language is `Scala`, if this matters.

**How can i define autocomplete pattern as shown above?**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the **surround templates**:

[image: surround]

You can find more details in help:

- [Surrounding Blocks of Code with Language Constructs](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/surrounding-blocks-of-code-with-language-constructs.html)

Comment: Keyboard Shortcut: CTR+ALT+T

Comment: Another easy way to access this is to use the global search hotkey, Shift Shift by default, then type 'surround' and select the Surround With entry

Comment: Keyboard Shortcut in macOS: ⌥+⌘+T

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can go to `File > Settings...` and under `Live Templates` add your own with,
Abbreviation: try

Template text:

```
try {
        // do something great
    } catch {
        case e: Exception => $END$ // handle me
    }
```

Applicable in Java: expression.
The `$VAL$` places the cursor there after you tab off of the "try".